# Storing and Accessing Values inside a Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below Winform for a game application I am developing:

[image: My Winform]

What I want to do is enter desired values under Beam Arcs and Beam Settings, select a weapon name in listBox1 then hit the right arrow button to store those settings in listBox2.  I want to be able to store multiple weapon types and when I click between them on listBox2, the Arcs and Settings values update appropriately.

This is my current code:

```
public class beamWeaponClass
{
    public string beamValue, beamActiveValue, beamArcsValue,
    beamBonusValue, beamCostValue, beamDamageValue, beamLoadValue,
    beamLockValue, beamNameValue, beamRangeValue, beamRecycleValue,
    listNameLabel;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return listNameLabel;
    }
}

public void addBeamWeaponButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    beamWeaponClass newBeamWeapon = new beamWeaponClass();
    newBeamWeapon.beamValue = "0 0 1 1 " + addedBeamWeaponsList.Items.Count.ToString(); // Beam
    newBeamWeapon.beamActiveValue = "0"; // Beam Active
    newBeamWeapon.beamArcsValue = calculateArcs(); // Beam Arcs
    newBeamWeapon.beamBonusValue = beamBonus.Text; // Beam Bonus
    newBeamWeapon.beamCostValue = beamCost.Text; // Beam Cost
    newBeamWeapon.beamDamageValue = "1"; // Beam Damage
    newBeamWeapon.beamLoadValue = "0"; // Beam Load
    newBeamWeapon.beamLockValue = "0"; // Beam Lock
    newBeamWeapon.beamNameValue = beamWeaponList.GetItemText(beamWeaponList.SelectedItem); // Beam Name
    newBeamWeapon.beamRangeValue = beamRange.Text; // Beam Range
    newBeamWeapon.beamRecycleValue = beamRecycle.Text; // Beam Recycle
    newBeamWeapon.listNameLabel = beamWeaponList.GetItemText(beamWeaponList.SelectedItem);

    addedBeamWeaponsList.Items.Add(newBeamWeapon);
}

private void selectedBeamWeapons_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //beamBonus.Text = newBeamWeapon.beamBonusValue;
    //beamCost.Text = newBeamWeapon.beamCost.Text;
    //beamRange.Text = newBeamWeapon.beamRange.Text; // Beam Range
    //beamRecycle.Text = newBeamWeapon.beamRecycle.Text;
}

private void removeBeamWeaponButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to use a class to store those values when I click the right arrow button.  I have then been attempting to see if those values are being stored with the `selectedBeamWeapons_SelectedIndexChanged()` method but I commented out that code because I was getting `The name 'newBeamWeapon' does not exist in the current context` errors.  The button itself works, at least to an extent.  Sending values from one listBox1 to listBox2 is working, I just don't know if those values are going with it.

[image: My Winform after button click]

The buttons on the right are to reorder, and to select one, modify its settings and save it.  I am not worried about that so much now, I think if I can nail storing and accessing, then changing should be pretty easy.

I don't know if I am even on the right track with storing the values let alone accessing them.  If someone can go over what I've done and let me know how I can access those stored settings, I would really appreciate it.

I hope that all made sense.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  Do prefer public properties over public fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `newBeamWeapon` as local variable in `addBeamWeaponButton_Click`. So it is visible there only. But in `selectedBeamWeapons_SelectedIndexChanged`, it is better to use the actual selection, as it could have changed through another user interaction as well (when the user clicks into the list).

```
var beamWeapon = addedBeamWeaponsList.SelectedItem as beamWeaponClass;
if (beamWeapon != null) {
    beamBonus.Text = beamWeapon.beamBonusValue;
    beamCost.Text = beamWeapon.beamCost.Text;
    beamRange.Text = beamWeapon.beamRange.Text; // Beam Range
    beamRecycle.Text = beamWeapon.beamRecycle.Text;
}
```

The `beamWeaponClass` is strange. Do you really want to store all those values as string? How do you want to perform arithmetic on those values?

Comment: Yeah the class is but it is that way because I need to output a text file with all these settings in a specific format. It is just the constraints I am working within so I can output a file this game can parse. I only need to perform arithmetic on 1 of those variables which I handle in the calculateArcs() method. Everything else is output as a string that gets concatenated into the correct format elsewhere in the application.